# Finding $\mathsf{E}(\sqrt{X})$, $\mathsf{Var}(\sqrt{X})$, mgf, and pdf of Exponential Family Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am learning about exponential families. I am attempting to solve the following problem.

> $X$ has pdf
>
> $$\frac{1}{2\theta^2}e^{−\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\theta}}I_{(0,\infty)}(x)$$
>   where $\theta \gt 0$. Find:
>
> $(a)$ $\mathsf{E}(\sqrt{X})$
>
> $(b)$ $\mathsf{Var}(\sqrt{X})$
>
> $(c)$ the mgf of $Y=\sqrt{X}$
>
> $(d)$ the pdf of $Y=\sqrt{X}$

I'm given that letting $c^{*}(\vec\eta)$ be $c^{*}(\vec\theta)$ expressed in terms of the natural parameters, for a full exponential family we have

$$\mathsf{E}(t_j(X))=-\frac{d}{d\eta_j}log(c^{*}(\vec\eta))$$

$$\mathsf{Var}\left(t_j(X)\right)=-\frac{d^2}{d\eta_j^2}log\left(c^{*}(\vec\eta)\right)$$

**Attempted Solution:**

$(a)$

My understanding is that we need to find functions $h(x)$, $c(\theta)$, $w(\theta)$, and $t(x)$ so that $$h(x)\cdot c(\theta)\cdot e^{w(\theta)t(x)}=\frac{1}{2\theta^2}e^{−\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\theta}}$$

We can let

$$h(x)=1, c(\theta)=\frac{1}{2\theta^2},w(\theta)=-\frac{1}{\theta},t(x)=\sqrt{x}$$

For a natural parameterization, we can use

$$\eta = -\frac{1}{\theta}, c^{*}(\eta)=\frac{1}{2\cdot(-\frac{1}{\eta})^2}=\frac{\eta^2}{2}$$

We have

$$\begin{align*}
\mathsf{E}(\sqrt{X})
&=-\frac{d}{d\eta}log\left(\frac{\eta^2}{2}\right)\\\\
&=-\frac{2}{\eta}\\\\
&=\frac{-2}{-\frac{1}{\theta}}\\\\
&=2\theta
\end{align*}$$

$(b)$

We have

$$\begin{align*}
\mathsf{Var}(\sqrt{X})
&=\frac{d}{d\eta}\left(-\frac{2}{\eta}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{2}{\eta^2}\\\\
&=\frac{2}{\left(-\frac{1}{\theta}\right)^2}\\\\
&=2\theta^2
\end{align*}$$

$(c)$

I'm given that for a full one-parameter family, the mgf of $t(x)$ is $\frac{c^*(\eta)}{c^*(\eta+t)}$

Thus, the mgf of $Y=\sqrt{X}$ is

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{c^*(\eta)}{c^*(\eta+t)}
&=\frac{\frac{\eta^2}{2}}{\frac{(\eta+t)^2}{2}}\\\\
&=\frac{\eta^2}{(\eta+t)^2}\\\\
&=\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{\theta}\right)^2}{\left(-\frac{1}{\theta}+t\right)^2}
\end{align*}$$

It's still not clear to me what exactly a full one-parameter family is or what characteristic of this particular example indicates that it is a full one-parameter family, but I made that assumption nonetheless.

$(d)$

I have

$$\int \frac{1}{2\theta^2}e^{−\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\theta}}=-\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\theta}}\left(\sqrt{x}+\theta\right)$$

so

$$F_X(x) = \begin{cases} {-\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\theta}}\left(\sqrt{x}+\theta\right)} & \text{$x \gt 0$} \\  0 & {x \leq 0}\end{cases}$$

Therefore

$$\begin{align*}
F_Y(y)
&=P(Y\leq y)\\\\
&=P(\sqrt{X}\leq y)\\\\
&=P(X\leq y^2)\\\\
&=F_X(y^2)\\\\
&=-\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-\frac{y}{\theta}}\left(y+\theta\right)
\end{align*}$$

Thus

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{e^{-\frac{y}{\theta}}y}{\theta^2}I_{(0,\infty)}(y)$$

Are these valid solutions?

Comment: Everything looks fine and the mgf will simplify to $(\theta  t-1)^{-2}$.